# Contacts has trouble syncing with the Google account. What to do?

Tags: macos, contacts, google, google-sync

[image]

I have Contacts (Version 8.0 (1365)) running under Mac OS X 10.9.1. I have it connected with my Google account. But it keeps showing that it is busy syncing. Changes made on other devices don't come through. (Other devices *do* sync with each other.) How can I solve this?

NB: After some time the "wheel" disappears, but still the new contact isn't there...

Comment: Is there anything shown in Console.app (Make sure *All Messages* is selected.) that is related to Contacts or syncing?  Have you tried deleting and re-adding the Google Account in "Internet Accounts" under System Preferences?

Comment: @ryebread 1. Console: hundreds (if not more) of "Contacts: CoreData: error: exception during obtainPermanentIDsForObjects: Fetching maximum primary key failed with userInfo of { NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 11; }". 2. I did turn off and back on Google Contacts in Internet Accounts, without effect. (I did not yet remove the whole account.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message:

```
Contacts: CoreData: error: exception during obtainPermanentIDsForObjects: Fetching maximum primary key failed with userInfo of { NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 11; }
```

I am guessing that the SQLite DB of your `Contacts.app` is corrupted.

I would recommend taking the following steps:

1. Export a backup archive of your contacts (if they are not all on Google)

   1. You can do this by going to `File > Export... > Contacts Archive`
   2. Quit `Contacts.app`
2. Delete the offending SQLite Database

   1. From the Finder, select `Go > Go To Folder` from the menu.
   2. Type in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/`
   3. Select all those files: `Edit > Select All`
   4. Put them in a folder: `File > New Folder With Selection`
   5. Move the folder to the Trash. (In case something goes wrong, we can restore everything)
3. Launch `Contacts.app` and re-create your Google account
4. Re-import your contacts archive (again, only if they are not all on google's servers.  Otherwise, just let it re-sync.)

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for your precise instructions. I think it worked. :) Thanks! 1. I did lose 1% of my contacts, but they _might_ have been "empty" to start with (i.e., nothing but a name). 2. I also don't see my groups anymore (but they are still there on Google). This might be something unrelated, as I don't see these on my other devices either.

Comment: You'll probably have to re-create your groups... I don't know that they sync. About the lost contacts, if you want to see if they were empty you could create a new user account as a test, and then restore the backup archive, or the files that you threw away.  That way, you wouldn't mess up your current user account, and wouldn't lose any contacts.  Glad it worked for you!